# Sum each element of two List<Integer>s into a new list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How to merge two lists to one list by included value of same index.
I have 2 lists and I want to merge two lists by included value of same index.
(If possible, please suggest me on way of java 8: Streams.)

```
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
List<String> b = Arrays.asList("10", "20", "30");
```

Output :

```
{"11", "22", "33"}
```

Comment: What should happen if the lists are of different lengths?

Comment: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-

Answer (score 3):

A solution that uses only standard library:

```
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
List<String> b = Arrays.asList("10", "20", "30");

List<String> c = IntStream.range(0, a.size())
                          .map(i -> Integer.parseInt(a.get(i)) + Integer.parseInt(b.get(i)))
                          .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that input lists store numbers as `String`, as specified in your example. Also, you could merge `map()` and `mapToObj()` calls into a single `mapToObj()` call but I wanted to leave it split for clarity.

It also assumes that both lists are of the same size, if they weren't, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use zip? https://github.com/poetix/protonpack has a nice library

```
StreamUtils.zip(a.stream(), b.stream(), (e1,e2) -> (Integer.parseInt(e1) + Integer.parseInt(e2)).toString())
```

Comment: @DamianLattenero Please do not solicit people to accept your answers. This is a place for the best answers, not the quickest answers. As it stands, you haven't even mentioned that this is not a core Java function

Comment: Don't forget to accept one answer, the one that was most useful for you @AeNetPhornphithak

Comment: @Michael you were right, I've never mentioned the library, thanks now I added it

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) you can use `zip`:

```
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
List<String> b = Arrays.asList("10", "20", "30");
List<String> c = Lists.adapt(a).zip(b)
        .collectInt(p -> Integer.parseInt(p.getOne()) +Integer.parseInt(p.getTwo()))
        .collect(Integer::toString);

System.out.println(c);
```

Output: `[11, 22, 33]`

You can also use `Collectors2` from Eclipse Collections with a `Stream`.

```
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
List<String> b = Arrays.asList("10", "20", "30");
List<String> c = a.stream().collect(Collectors2.zip(b))
        .collectInt(p -> Integer.parseInt(p.getOne()) + Integer.parseInt(p.getTwo()))
        .collect(Integer::toString);

System.out.println(c);
```

Output: `[11, 22, 33]`

**Note**: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.